# Predefining own load balancing strategy with Zuul in Spring application

Tags: load-balancing, spring-cloud, netflix-zuul, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-netflix

I'm trying to experiment with spring cloud stack, mainly with Eureka and Zuul from Netflix. After some time I managed to create Eureka Server along with two separate clients with some rest API which register themselves with that server and another one which I'm using as a server load-balancer to proxy requests to those two instances.

**PROBLEM**

I would like to define my own load balancing strategy as I read that Zuul uses Round Robin by default. Is there any specific naming convention for that in Zuul as I had no luck looking for it neither in docs nor guides.

Comment: zuul uses ribbon. check the ribbon section http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Edgware.SR3/single/spring-cloud.html#_customizing_the_ribbon_client. Specifically, you would want to implement an `IRule`.

Comment: does it mean that I have to put it on my classpath and preconfigure using @Configuration bean ? Does it also force me to somehow depend on Ribbon load balancing rather than the one Zuul provides ?

Comment: Yes, Zuul doesn't have it's own load balancing strategies. It uses ribbon.

Answer (score 2):

Zuul's round robin load balancing only works as advertised within the scope of a refresh of the discovery client which happens every few seconds by default.

When Zuul refreshes its discovery client the list of server instances is shuffled randomly by the code in `com.netflix.discovery.shared.Applications` and cannot be configured out. This shuffle breaks the stateful logic in `com.netflix.loadbalancer.RoundRobinRule` that maintains a 'last position' in the list of servers so it can do its round-robin logic.

Bear this in mind when you're implementing your own rule that selects a server. You may need to sort by instance id or something like that to undo the shuffle that the discovery client did.

To implement your own rule you just need to provide a bean that implements `com.netflix.loadbalancer.IRule`. What we did is extend the abstract class `com.netflix.loadbalancer.AbstractLoadBalancerRule`. The `choose()` method is where you do your work.